# Dynamically loaded input box does nothining

Tags: angularjs

So I have some html that gets loaded into the #panel div dynamically depending on which questionNumber the user is on. This is not all of the code but all of the relevant code I think. Anyway, the `<input>` get's loaded into the page but it doesn't actually do anything. what am I missing here? I have the same problem when the questionNumber === 1, where the binded variables just show up as `{{variable}}` etc

```
var readingController = function (scope, Romanize){
        scope.usersRomanization;
        //alert(scope.usersRomanization);
}

var app = angular.module('Tutorials', ['functions', 'tutorials']).controller('getAnswers', function ($scope, $element, Position, Romanize) {
$scope.sectionNumber = Position.sectionNumber;
if ($scope.sectionNumber === 0){
    $('#panel').html('<div ng-controller="readingController"><input ng-model="usersRomanization"></input></div>');
    readingController($scope, Romanize);
}

<body ng-controller="getAnswers">
    <div  id="panel">
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You can't have jQuery in your controllers. See [How do I “think in AngularJS” if I have a jQuery background?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/how-do-i-think-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background).

Comment: Then how else should I load this html into the page based on questionNumber? Despite the fact it's against conventions shouldn't this still technically work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add HTML to the DOM, you have to tell Angular to $compile it.  This should be done in a directive.  You'll need to inject `$compile` then do something like this:

```
var content = '<div ng-controller=...></div>';
var compiled = $compile(content)(scope);
// then put the content where you want
```

Or better, define a directive and use a `template`, which will automatically get compiled for you by Angular.

Other alternatives are ng-include (which will compile the loaded content for you) and ng-switch, which would allow you to put the templates into the HTML.

Comment: ok then in that case how do I dynamically load the directive based on questionNumber?

Comment: Try ng-include or ng-switch.  It is hard to say without knowing how many questions you have, or where your templates are coming from -- are your templates in separate files or can you use (script)[http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:script] to put them into your Javascript?  If so, use ng-include.  With ng-switch you can put all your templates into your HTML.

Comment: sorry I should have said based on sectionNumber, at the moment there are only 2 sections but there will be more in future

Comment: looks like ng-switch is exactly what I'm looking for, I will just include the html in the document body :)